# What is the initial value of ViewPerspective after loading image using LeadTools?

Tags: leadtools-sdk

When loading images using LeadTools API, what would be the initial value of ViewPerspective?

My experiments with below code snippet revealed it is always BOTTOM_LEFT (4).

```
BITMAPHANDLE LeadBitmap2;
L_INT nRet = L_ConvertFromDIB(&LeadBitmap2, sizeof(BITMAPHANDLE), (BITMAPINFO*)pucTestBuffer, pDIBits);
// Here LeadBitmap2.ViewPerspective was BOTTOM_LEFT

BITMAPHANDLE LeadBitmapChanged;
L_ChangeBitmapViewPerspective(&LeadBitmapChanged, &LeadBitmap2, sizeof(BITMAPHANDLE), TOP_LEFT);
// Here LeadBitmapChanged.ViewPerspective was TOP_LEFT as expected.
```

Here I converted LeadTool Bitmap with changed perspective to DIB and created a new LeadTool Bitmap using L_ConvertFromDIB()

```
L_HDIB hDIB = L_ConvertToDIB(&LeadBitmapChanged, DIB_BITMAPINFOHEADER);
unsigned char* pBmi = (unsigned char*)::GlobalLock(hDIB);

BITMAPHANDLE LeadBitmap4;
nRet = L_ConvertFromDIB(&LeadBitmap4, sizeof(BITMAPHANDLE), (BITMAPINFO*)pBmi, 
    pBmi + sizeof(BITMAPHANDLE) + ((BITMAPINFO*)pBmi)->bmiHeader.biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD));
```

Here LeadBitmap4.ViewPerspective was again BOTTOM_LEFT. Could we assume it is always BOTTOM_LEFT when you load image using LeadTools? LeadTools documentation doesn't say anything about the default/initial value of ViewPerspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view perspective is not fixed for all images but depends on the image format. For example, when loading PNG file form disk, the view perspective will be TOP_LEFT.
For loading Windows BMP files, or when converting a Windows Device Independent Bitmap (DIB), the view perspective is usually BOTTOM_LEFT. 
For the TIFF file format, it can be almost any view perspective depending on the orientation tag in TIFF itself.

If you want the image to be of a specific orientation, you can always change the view perspective by calling "L_ChangeBitmapViewPerspective" after loading or converting the image.
For more information read the topic for the L_ChangeBitmapViewPerspective() function in our help files.